# Disable ASP.NET logging to the console when using Serilog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I don't want ASP.NET to speak, and sit in the corner silent. How can I stop these types of logs:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[1]
      Failed to validate the token.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com - - - 401 0 - 114.5870ms
```

I've tried setting it to a higher log level via my appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Verbose",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G}[{Level:u3}] ** {Message} ** ({SourceContext}) {NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
      }]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change also the logging level in the ASP .NET configuration. In your appsettings.json you can specify a different level of logging:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

So your appsettings.json file should look similar to:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G}[{Level:u3}] ** {Message} ** ({SourceContext}) {NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
      }]
  },
```

You can check this page also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging